# Find nested components in Angular directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a problem in Angular 4. I have a subpage which has the structure:

```
<div tableOfContents>
    <page></page>

    <static-page>
        <page></page>
    </static-page>

    <dynamic-page>
        <page></page
    </dynamic-page>
</div>
```

and I would like to collect all Page components in tableOfContents directive. I tried `@ContentChildren (Page, {descendants: true})`, but it only returns me a direct child from `<div tableOfContents>`, is there some way? Static-page and dynamic-page will be dynamically added / removed on the page. `@ViewChildren(Page)` returns undefined

Comment: plunker for better overview of problem https://plnkr.co/edit/OxFk64xFhX09ArB0O8hd?p=preview

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  You aren't asking about the **problem** you are trying to solve;  rather, you are asking about a **solution** that isn't working that is being used to solve some unknown problem.  What exactly is the point of "collecting" all the `Page` components?.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you only have one option since you can't query for components that goes into sub-components.

What you can do is store the `page` instances in a service and fetch them from there in your `tableOfContents` directive.

Something like this should suffice:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {PageComponent} from '<path-to-page>';

@Injectable()

export class PageInstancesService {

  public instances = [];

  constructor() {}
}
```

Then in your `page` component you'd do:

```
constructor(
  private pis: PageInstancesService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.pis.instances.push({id: <some-unique-id>, instance: this});
}
```

To push a new instance. To remove an instance once it's destroyed you will add `ngOnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {

  const i = // Function to get instance index in array goes here

  this.pis.instances.splice(i, 1);
}
```